# How to remove Hubstaff from Ubuntu

Tags: 15.04, 64-bit, uninstall

I recently had to install HubStaff (https://hubstaff.com/). Now I need to remove this software from my Linux machine running Ubuntu 15.04 (64 Bit). I browsed their support section (support.hubstaff.com) but could not find a single article there describing the process.

I went a little further and tried to find if their installer had some kind of option (--help) that could work for uninstalling the software. Oddly, I didn't find any option in it, I only saw options like "help screen", "changing temporary directory" etc. Nothing too useful there.

Another odd thing is never could find anywhere (by Googling) where is this thing installed in the Linux directory structure.

Now I'm feeling really suspicious about this software.

It'd be really helpful if somebody could show me how to uninstall Hubstaff.

Comment: How did you install it? Did you not contact their support?

Comment: Their site has an installer script for linux (.sh). I already contacted their support but no responses whatsoever.

Comment: Paste the content of the installer script here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and add a link in your question.

Comment: The installer is huge for pasting as text (10 MB) with a payload added at the end. Would it be good enough if I just add the initial text part where various bash instructions are? @A.B.

Comment: ok, the script part...

Comment: Thanks for considering.
Here's the bash part
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12640087/

I also uploaded the installer here if need be (Since you can't download it from their site without first creating an account, 14 day free trial)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5jqKvYrJTqnbVdScXZVT0JQZTQ/view?usp=sharing

Hope this helps.

Comment: What directory did you install it to? If it's not a standard system path, and all the content is installed to a single directory, just delete that path, and the .desktop file for the launcher, if there is one.

Comment: I did not specify any directory, the default one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand your suspicions but I use Hubstaff (for Windows) and don't have anything to worry about.

You can remove Hubstaff on Linux by navigating to the Hubstaff folder and dragging the "uninstall-Hubstaff.sh" file to a terminal window. A new support article will be published on this soon.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. That's a relief.

For those of you who might be wondering where can you locate the Uninstallation script, you can run
`sudo updatedb;`
`locate Hubstaff | grep uninstall;`

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling on Linux
Navigate to the Hubstaff folder (usually inside your home folder) and drag the uninstall-Hubstaff.sh file to a terminal window. Please follow the steps below:

STEP 1

Right click the .sh file and click “Properties”.

STEP 2

Then make sure you allow executing the file as a program.

STEP 3

Drag and drop the .sh file into the terminal window (or simply run the file path from the terminal window) and hit enter. This will get Hubstaff uninstalled from your computer.

To delete Hubstaff data directory navigate to: **~/.local/share/hubStaff**

From: https://support.hubstaff.com/uninstall-hubstaff/#uninstall-linux